# how to return multiple double type variables from a public method in java?

Tags: java, variables, object, methods

I have a public method from where I want to pass the double variables to my main method where I again call them :

(in the actual code, the public method is called several times and the same values need to be returned to the caller)

```
 public double ReturnDoubleVariables() 
  {
    double ret1 promptUserForInput("1st Varaible", );
    double ret2 promptUserForInput("2nd Varaible", );
    double ret3 promptUserForInput("3rd Varaible", );
    double ret4 promptUserForInput("4th Varaible", );
    double ret5 promptUserForInput("5th Varaible", )

    return (ret1, ret2,...,ret5);
   }


  private void execute0() {

   Simulation simulation_0 = getActiveSimulation();
        scalarProfile_0.getMethod(ConstantScalarProfileMethod.class).getQuantity().setValue(ret1);

        scalarProfile_0.getMethod(ConstantScalarProfileMethod.class).getQuantity().setValue(ret2);

        scalarProfile_0.getMethod(ConstantScalarProfileMethod.class).getQuantity().setValue(ret3);

        scalarProfile_0.getMethod(ConstantScalarProfileMethod.class).getQuantity().setValue(ret4);

        scalarProfile_0.getMethod(ConstantScalarProfileMethod.class).getQuantity().setValue(ret5);

   }
```

I am having trouble in returning multiple variables from the public method and then I do not know how should I call the variables in the main method?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can return an array :

```
 public double[] ReturnDoubleVariables() 
 {
    double ret1 = promptUserForInput("1st Varaible", );
    double ret2 = promptUserForInput("2nd Varaible", );
    double ret3 = promptUserForInput("3rd Varaible", );
    double ret4 = promptUserForInput("4th Varaible", );
    double ret5 = promptUserForInput("5th Varaible", )

    return new double[]{ret1, ret2, ret3, ret4, ret5};
  }
```

or :

```
 public double[] ReturnDoubleVariables() 
 {
    double[] ret = new double[5];
    ret[0] = promptUserForInput("1st Varaible", );
    ret[1] = promptUserForInput("2nd Varaible", );
    ret[2] = promptUserForInput("3rd Varaible", );
    ret[3] = promptUserForInput("4th Varaible", );
    ret[4] = promptUserForInput("5th Varaible", )

    return ret;
  }
```

Comment: Hi Eran thank you for the post.. it answers my first question. However  I am not able to call these variables in the main method.. can you suggest something for this as well>?

Answer (score 2):

You can return a  List of Double values:

```
public List<Double> ReturnDoubleVariables() 
  {
    double ret1=promptUserForInput("1st Varaible", );
    double ret2=promptUserForInput("2nd Varaible", );
    double ret3=promptUserForInput("3rd Varaible", );
    double ret4=promptUserForInput("4th Varaible", );
    double ret5=promptUserForInput("5th Varaible", )
    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
    list.add(ret1);    
    list.add(ret2);
    ...
    list.add(ret5);
    return list;
   }
```

Or you can create a class for the reurn values:

```
public class RetDouble{
   private double ret1;
   private double ret2;
   ... 
   private double ret5;
   //getter and setter;
}
public RetDouble ReturnDoubleVariables() 
  {
    double ret1=promptUserForInput("1st Varaible", );
    double ret2=promptUserForInput("2nd Varaible", );
    double ret3=promptUserForInput("3rd Varaible", );
    double ret4=promptUserForInput("4th Varaible", );
    double ret5=promptUserForInput("5th Varaible", );

    RetDouble r = new RetDouble();
    r.setRet1(ret1);
    r.setRet2(ret2);
    ...
    r.setRet5(ret5);
    return r;
   }
```

Comment: Hi Jens  Thanks a lot for your answer.. the method works for me. However I  cannot call the variables returned in this method to my main method.. Can you tell me how I should do that?

Comment: @Jaiscience which one you mean. the first or the second?

Comment: @Jaiscience sorry but i can't get you.

Comment: Hi Jens    If you scroll on top of to my original post, after the public method, i've laid out another private method named : private void execute0() { *******code block********)    ... here I've called those variables that I returned from my method " ReturnDoubleVariables() "   but I am not able to call the variables in execute0() method.. can you tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: @Jaiscience You have to call the funtion `ReturnDoubleVariables()` and then you get the return value. If you use my secon Example you get `RetDouble` if you call `RetDouble r = ReturnDoubleVariables()` and then you can get ret1 by calling `r.getRet1()`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Jens  thanks a lot for your time and patience.. To be honest I am implementing the solution posted by @Eran (topmost solution)     "return new double[ ]{ret1,ret2,ret3...} " (This seems more simple, as I am not a computer guy at all) will be really kind if you could suggest somethings on this lines considering I am implementing Eran's method of returning the double variable

Comment: @Jaiscience So i find my solution is better. But if you would like to use the solution of @Eran you have to call `double[] r = ReturnDoubleVariables() ; double ret1 = r[0]`

Comment: Hi jens.. I really did not mean any offence or gave my judgement as I am not in any position to do so due to my complete lack of knowledge in programming.. i found @Eran's solution easier to understand .. also I cannot edit any class (again because I don't know how to) as this will render the continuum mechanics code illegible by the solver   thank you for all the help and your patience

Answer (score 1):

You could return a `double[]` like

```
public double[] ReturnDoubleVariables() {
    return new double[] { promptUserForInput("1st Varaible"),
            promptUserForInput("2nd Varaible"),
            promptUserForInput("3rd Varaible"),
            promptUserForInput("4th Varaible"),
            promptUserForInput("5th Varaible") };
}
```

Also, Java method names start with a lower case letter (by convention) so the above should be `returnDoubleVariables`.

Answer (score 1):

Bundle them together in one object, preferably a `List<Double>` (unless you know in advance how many you'd like to return and then use a simple array).

**List Example**

```
public List<Double> ReturnDoubleVariables() {

     List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();

     //consider looping instead...
     list.add(promptUserForInput("1st Varaible", ));
     list.add(promptUserForInput("2nd Varaible", ));
     list.add(promptUserForInput("3rd Varaible", ));
     list.add(promptUserForInput("4th Varaible", ));
     list.add(promptUserForInput("5th Varaible", ));

     return list;
```

}

**Array Example**

```
public double[] ReturnDoubleVariables() {

     double[] arr = new double[5];

     //consider looping instead...
     arr[0] = list.add(promptUserForInput("1st Varaible", );
     arr[1] = promptUserForInput("2nd Varaible", );
     arr[2] = promptUserForInput("3rd Varaible", );
     arr[3] = promptUserForInput("4th Varaible", );
     arr[4] = promptUserForInput("5th Varaible", );

     return arr;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

return it with an `Array` , or using collections like `List`(`ArrayList,LinkedList`),`Sets` etc

```
public double[] ReturnDoubleVariables() {
return new double[] { promptUserForInput("1st Varaible"),
        promptUserForInput("2nd Varaible"),
        promptUserForInput("3rd Varaible"),
        promptUserForInput("4th Varaible"),
        promptUserForInput("5th Varaible") };
```

}

or

```
public ArrayList<Double> ReturnDoubleVariables() {
ArrayList<Double> destinationArray = new ArrayList<Double>();
destinationArray.add("1st Varaible")
destinationArray.add("2nd Varaible");
destinationArray.add("3rd Varaible");
return destinationArrayList;
```

}